# How to insert new item with multi users ids using batch element?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services, lookup-column, multiple-values

I am getting issue while creating a new item with multiselection peoplepicker field named multiusers with ids, i am trying below code for stringbatch

```
string strbatch="<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'><Field Name='multiusers'>812;#813</Field></Method>";
```

but its not getting created with multiple users in list
Please help to track this
Thanks
Rehman

Comment: is anyone there to answer this please?

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute batch request, data format of user field is:

```
{user id};#{user name}
```

For example, we have two users like `spUser1` (user `Id` is `1`)
 & `spUser2` (user `Id` is `2`).

For single user field, the data format should look like according to above format

```
1;#spUser1
```

Or

```
2;#spUser2
```

Now, if our user field allows multiple users and we wish to insert `spUser1` and `spUser2`, then the data format will be

```
1;#spUser1;#2;#spUser2
```

If I simplify above format, it should look like following

```
{format for single user};#{format for single user};#{format for single user}
```

Comment: hi Atish, thanks for ur reply. I have to pass only ids here, then in batch element it will automatically pickup the users. I tried passing values as follows example: <1,2>,<1;2>,<1;#2>.but nothing worked, only first value getting updated Please help me how can i pass with ids

Comment: it seems your format is not still correct. Please follow what I have mentioned. It requires user id and name.